# Eigen-values not converged, warning in Quantum espresso

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso

I am running a simple example of `vc-relax`/`scf` for aluminum using PBE pseudo-potential.Setting are given below

```
 &control                                                            
    calculation='vc-relax'                                           
    restart_mode='from_scratch',                                     
    pseudo_dir =.                                                    
    outdir=./tmp/,                                                   
    prefix='al'                                                      
    tprnfor = .true.                                                 
    tstress = .true.                                                 
    etot_conv_thr=1D-06                                              
    forc_conv_thr=1D-03                                              
 /                                                                   
 &system                                                             
    ibrav=  2,A=4.04,nat=  1, ntyp= 1, ecutwfc =30.0,                
    occupations='smearing', smearing='mp', degauss=0.05              
 /                                                                   
 &electrons                                                          
  conv_thr    = 1.D-6,                                               
  mixing_mode='plain',                                               
  startingwfc='atomic-random',                                              
  mixing_beta = 0.7D0,                                               
  diagonalization = "cg"                                             
 /                                                                   
&ions                                                                
ion_dynamics='bfgs'                                                  
/                                                                    
&cell                                                                
cell_dynamics='bfgs'                                                 
/                                                                    
                                                                     
ATOMIC_SPECIES                                                       
 Al  26.98 Al.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF                              
ATOMIC_POSITIONS alat                                                
 Al 0.00 0.00 0.00                                                   
K_POINTS automatic
21 21 21 0 0 0
```

I am getting warning in some of the scf cycle as

```
     iteration #  1     ecut=    30.00 Ry     beta= 0.70
     CG style diagonalization
     c_bands:  1 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  5 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  3 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  2 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  4 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  3 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  3 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  4 eigenvalues not converged
     c_bands:  4 eigenvalues not converged
```

I have changed `mixing_mode`,`mixing_beta`,`Kpoints`,`ecutwfc`,`smearing` `startingwfc`,`diagonalization` and convergence tolerances, to all extent but warning still exists.
What is perfect solution to this warning?

Comment: Did you check the [userguide](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/pw_user_guide/node21.html)?

Answer (score 9):

Please go through the [userguide](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/Doc/pw_user_guide/node21.html). At the bottom, it has some nice suggestions. Check this [mail thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@lists.quantum-espresso.org/msg38442.html) also.

> Does the program stops because too many errors have not converged or,
> the  calculation keeps going on ?

If the calculation did not stop and keeps going on, then you can ignore these warnings. Please do some convergence tests before you proceed for `vc-relax`. I did calculations for Al, I even got convergence error in first iteration but subsequent calculations were fine.

[Al.vc-relax.in]

```
 &CONTROL
                 calculation = 'vc-relax' ,
                restart_mode = 'from_scratch' ,
                      outdir = '.' ,
                  pseudo_dir = '.' ,
                      prefix = 'Al' ,
 /
 &SYSTEM
                       ibrav = 2,
                   celldm(1) = 7.6897,
                         nat = 1,
                        ntyp = 1,
                     ecutwfc = 80 ,
                 occupations = 'smearing' ,
                     degauss = 0.02 ,
                    smearing = 'mp' ,
 /
 &ELECTRONS
 /
 &IONS
 /
 &CELL
               cell_dynamics = 'bfgs' ,
 /
ATOMIC_SPECIES
   Al  26.98  Al.pbe-nl-rrkjus_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS alat
   Al    0.000000000    0.000000000    0.000000000
K_POINTS automatic
  20 20 20  0 0 0
```

[Al.vc-relax.out]

```
Begin final coordinates
     new unit-cell volume =    111.15446 a.u.^3 (    16.47139 Ang^3 )
     density =      2.71995 g/cm^3

CELL_PARAMETERS (alat=  7.68970000)
  -0.496275584  -0.000000000   0.496275584
   0.000000000   0.496275584   0.496275584
  -0.496275584   0.496275584   0.000000000

ATOMIC_POSITIONS (alat)
Al            0.0000000000        0.0000000000        0.0000000000
End final coordinates
```

[Al.eos]

```
# equation of state: birch 1st order.  chisq =   0.5139D-05
# a0 =  7.6897 a.u., k0 =  678 kbar, dk0 =  4.27 d2k0 =  0.000 emin =   -5.03767
# a0 =  4.06919 Ang, k0 =  67.8 GPa,  V0 =   113.67 (a.u.)^3,  V0 =   16.84 A^3 

#########################################################################
# Lat.Par       E_calc        E_fit       E_diff    Pressure      Enthalpy
# a.u.            Ry           Ry            Ry        GPa           Ry
#########################################################################
  5.60000      -4.52379      -4.52017    -0.00362     518.54       -2.97618
  5.80000      -4.66251      -4.66460     0.00208     364.14       -3.45508
  6.00000      -4.76977      -4.77322     0.00346     255.35       -3.83242
  6.20000      -4.85181      -4.85448     0.00267     178.18       -4.13015
  6.40000      -4.91365      -4.91472     0.00107     123.13       -4.36511
  6.60000      -4.95932      -4.95872    -0.00060      83.70       -4.55036
  6.80000      -4.99207      -4.99014    -0.00193      55.39       -4.69607
  7.00000      -5.01447      -5.01177    -0.00270      35.05       -4.81018
  7.20000      -5.02866      -5.02579    -0.00287      20.44       -4.89899
  7.40000      -5.03643      -5.03388    -0.00255      10.00       -4.96759
  7.60000      -5.03924      -5.03734    -0.00191       2.57       -5.02006
  7.80000      -5.03820      -5.03721    -0.00100      -2.65       -5.05954
  8.00000      -5.03420      -5.03429     0.00009      -6.25       -5.08860
  8.20000      -5.02805      -5.02924     0.00119      -8.68       -5.10937
  8.40000      -5.02050      -5.02254     0.00205     -10.24       -5.12368
  8.60000      -5.01207      -5.01462     0.00254     -11.18       -5.13294
  8.80000      -5.00306      -5.00577     0.00271     -11.66       -5.13815
  9.00000      -4.99371      -4.99627     0.00256     -11.82       -5.14014
  9.20000      -4.98419      -4.98631     0.00212     -11.74       -5.13957
  9.40000      -4.97465      -4.97605     0.00140     -11.50       -5.13698
  9.60000      -4.96521      -4.96562     0.00042     -11.15       -5.13281
  9.80000      -4.95596      -4.95513    -0.00083     -10.72       -5.12745
 10.00000      -4.94697      -4.94465    -0.00232     -10.25       -5.12118
 10.20000      -4.93828      -4.93424    -0.00403      -9.76       -5.11423
```

[image: etot_vs_alat]
[image: etot_vs_ecut]
[image: etot_vs_k]